# Calculating azimuth between 2 points

Tags: qgis, expression, azimuth

I have been trying to use the azimuth expression function editor between 2 points.  However, I am not getting it to work.  I am obviously misunderstanding how to create the expression itself.  This is what I have

```
=  degrees( azimuth( make_point( "PrefRef"  'TR 15 NW 100' ), make_point( "PrefRef"  'TR 15 NW 114' )))
```

PrefRef being the point label and ID.

> Expression is invalid Error is  Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected
>   EQ
>
> Eval Error: No root node! Parsing failed?

I am using QGIS 2.18

Comment: Remove the equal sign at the beginning and add a delimiter to your make_point function. e.g. `make_point( "PrefRef",  'TR 15 NW 100' )`. Also make_point does not accept a string as point. You have to enter coordinates as number or field e.g. `make_point( "FieldContainingCoordinates",  13.44556677 )`.

Answer (score 2):

Azimuth function needs two point geometries, but if you have point geometries in a layer you don't need to "make the points"; you can read the geometry of that features instead.

Assuming that you have a Point geometry type vector layer named *'points'*, and you want to know the azimuth betwwen the point geometry of the features of that layer that have the values *'TR 15 NW 100'* and *'TR 15 NW 114'* in the *'PrefRef'* field, in degrees, you can use the following expression:

```
degrees(
  azimuth(
    geometry(
      get_feature(
        'points', 'PrefRef', 'TR 15 NW 100')),
    geometry(
      get_feature(
        'points', 'PrefRef', 'TR 15 NW 114'))))
```